# automatic close of bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal which I want to close when all values have been loaded.
Following is the code opening the modal -

```
    function open(){
    console.log("open modal");
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/view1.html',
        scope: $scope,
    });
};
```

view1.html

```
    <div class="modal-header">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div>
        <progressbar class="progress-striped active" max="100" type='success' value="progress"></progressbar>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I want to close the modal when value of scope variable progress becomes 100, how can I go about it?

Comment: I edited my post with a fiddle that should guide you forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller code

```
...
function open(){
    console.log("open modal");
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        controller: 'modalController'
        templateUrl: 'views/view1.html',
        scope: $scope,
    });
}) // End of the actual page controller
.controller('modalController', function($scope, $modalInstance, $interval, $timeout) {
    $scope.progress = $scope.$parent.progress;
    $interval(function() { if ($scope.progress < 100) $scope.progress += 1 }, 50);
    $scope.$watch(function() {return $scope.progress}, function() {
        if ($scope.progress >= 100) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $modalInstance.close();
            }, 1000)
        }
    })
})
```

For the exact situation of yours:

```
.controller('modalController', function($scope, $modalInstance, $timeout) {
    $scope.$watch(function() {return $scope.$parent.progress}, function() {
        if ($scope.$parent.progress >= 100) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $modalInstance.close();
            }, 1000)
        }
    })
})
```

Working fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/n0fbo3t3/

Comment: Scope variable progress is getting modified in the first controller and I want to put a watch on the updated values of progress. Above code is making a copy of the progress variable and changing it in the second controller.

Comment: Yeh, I just wanted to simulate the situation in the plunker. In your situation, you'll want to $watch $scope.$parent.progress instead. I edited my post accordingly.